# htaccess file for static CE Cache also redirect www

Tags: ce-cache

I am currently using the htaccess rules that CE Cache recommends when setting up a static cache:

```
#------------------- remove trailing slash -------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

#------------------- index.php -------------------
#strip index.php from the URL if that is all that is given
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,NS,L,QSA]
#strip index.php/* from the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

#------------------- CE Cache Static Driver -------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ACT|URL [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/ce_cache/8203ba/static%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) /_static_cache_handler.php?%{REQUEST_URI}/index\.html [L,QSA]

#------------------- EE -------------------
#rewrite all non-image/js/css urls back to index.php if they are not files or directories
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, I'd like to add in a redirect so if somebody visits at www.mydomain it goes to mydomain. I've tried a few things that I think should work with no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add next lines at the beginning of .htaccess right after RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```